# zipcode range query optimization

Tags: mysql, zipcode

im trying to build a search where you find places by entering a zipcode.

I used this guide https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.phpgangsta.de%2Feine-plz-umkreissuche-in-php&edit-text=

The search will try to lookup the zipcodes through 2 countries. 
At a specific search i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13 bytes) in
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT
dest.plz,
dest.ort,
ACOS(
SIN(RADIANS(src.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.lat))
+ COS(RADIANS(src.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.lat))
* COS(RADIANS(src.lon) - RADIANS(dest.lon))
) * 6380 AS distance
FROM geodb_data dest
CROSS JOIN geodb_data src
WHERE src.plz = $zipEncode
AND dest.plz <> src.plz
HAVING distance < $distanceEncode
ORDER BY distance;
```

My question, how can i optimize this query?

Comment: You can try the extensions for spatial data:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html.

Comment: Just curious, is it quicker to substitute "HAVING distance" with "WHERE ACOS(...etc..." ?

Comment: I would also like to know if this would be much faster

Comment: There is an SQL generator for creating the radius around a zipcode with different levels of accuracy (how curved do you want the line - http://www.zipcodeapi.com/API#radiusSql. It generates generic SQL that you would then modify for your own database.